# Why does CALL SET work differently in a CMD Windows versus a .CMD file?

Tags: string, windows, cmd, set

I am trying to use the Windows CMD `SET` string manipulation versions in a programmatic way. The two versions of `SET` are ...

```
SET New_String=%String:Old_Text=New_Text%
```

In variable `String` replace `Old_Text` with `New_Text`, and return result in variable `New_String`.

```
SET New_String=%String:~Number_Of_Chars_To_Skip,Number_Of_Chars_To_Keep%
```

In variable `String` extract `Number_Of_Chars_To_Keep` after skipping `Number_Of_Chars_To_Skip`, and return result in variable `New_String`

`Old_Text, New_Text, Number_Of_Chars_To_Skip, Number_Of_Chars_To_Keep` must all be literals, not variables. So, typical usage would be like this ...

```
SET New_String=%String:abcd=fghi%
SET New_String=%String:~2,4%
```

Usage like this won't work ...

```
SET New_String=%String:%Old_Text%=%New_Text%%
SET New_String=%String:~%Skip_Count%,%Keep_Count%%
```

To do the above two `SET`s you have to `CALL SET`, like ...

```
CALL SET New_String=%%String:%Old_Text%=%New_Text%%%
CALL SET New_String=%%String:~%Skip_Count%,%Keep_Count%%%
```

So, I have this following test code fragment ...

```
SET "Chars=" & SET "String=0123456789" & SET "Skip=1" & SET "Keep=3"
CALL SET Chars=%%String:~%Skip%,%Keep%%%
ECHO Chars="%Chars%" (expected to be "123")
```

From a CMD file this works correctly. The `CALL` has been expanded to `SET Chars=%string:~1,3%` and has returned the expected result 123. But, and a big but it is, from a CMD Window (with the same variables) the exact same `CALL SET` returns this ...

```
%0123456789Skip%,3%%
```

Why doesn't this work in a CMD Window? I researched around and haven't found any info explaining why.

Answer (score 1):

According to the thread [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts), batch files and command lines are parsed differently, particularly when it comes to environment variable expansion.

The batch file parser replaces two consecutive percent signs by one literal one, while the command line parser does not. Hence `CALL SET Chars=%%String:~%Skip%,%Keep%%%` works within a batch file but not in `cmd`.

To achieve the same resut in `cmd`, you could use this:

```
CALL SET Chars=%^String:~%Skip%,%Keep%%
```

Actually, this does nothing but specifying a variable named `^String`, which is expected to be not defined. In contrast to the batch file parser, the command line parser does not replace an undefined variable by an empty string, so `^String` is kept literally. Regard that the `^` is handled after `%` variable expansion. Variables `%Skip%` and `%Keep%` are expanded as expected, so the resulting expression is `SET Chars=%String:~1,3%`.

To prove that, simply do `SET String=something`, so the result is going to be `ome`.

---

Note that the quoted `SET` syntax `CALL SET "Chars=%^String:~%Skip%,%Keep%%"` fails, because this hides the escape character `^` from the parser. However, you can use escaped quotation marks instead:

```
CALL SET ^"Chars=%^String:~%Skip%,%Keep%%^"
```